# Having problems on moving a rectangle figure using threads

Tags: java

I'm having some problems on an exercise from my Java class, i made two rectangles on the game and i need that those figures move from one side to another. I already have the movement class and made the instance of the thread of the movement but it doesn't seem to move.

This is the code i have atm:
Entity class

```
class Entity implements Drawable{
Point pos;
Rectangle body;
boolean rigid;

public Entity(){
    pos = new Point(0,0);
    body = new Rectangle(pos, new Dimension(0,0));
}

public Entity(Point p, Dimension d){
    pos = new Point(p);
    body = new Rectangle(pos, d);
}

public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    pos = new Point(x,y);
    body = new Rectangle(pos, new Dimension(width, height));
}

public BufferedImage getActualImage(){
    Dimension d = body.getSize();
    return new BufferedImage(d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
}
}
```

This class is the game environment and where i add the objects on the window.

```
class Field extends JPanel{
Player p1;
int i=0;
static ArrayList<Entity> objects  = new ArrayList<Entity>();


private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
};

public Field(){

    //Implementar patron de disen/o
    p1 = setupPlayer();
    Game.objects.add(p1);

    //Player p2 = new Player();
    //p2.setImageRightRun("hero\\run.png");
    //Game.objects.add(p2);

    Entity e1 = new Entity(0, 520, 600, 50);
    Blocks block1 = new Blocks(260, 370, 100, 20);
    Blocks block2 = new Blocks(190, 440, 100, 20);
    Goal block3 = new Goal(300, 270, 50,50);
    Game.objects.add(e1);
    Game.objects.add(block1);
    Game.objects.add(block2);
    Game.objects.add(block3);
    new Thread(new MovementBlock(block1)).start(); //movement thread//
    PlayerBehaviour pb = new PlayerBehaviour(p1);
    this.addKeyListener(pb);
    Timer tick = new Timer(20, actionListener);
    tick.setInitialDelay(0);
    tick.start();
}
```

The block class

```
    class Blocks extends Entity{
    public Blocks(int x, int y, int ancho, int largo){
        super(x,y,ancho,largo);
    }
}
```

And the thread for the movement

```
    class MovementBlock implements Runnable{
    Blocks block;
    int velX = 2;
    public MovementBlock(Blocks block){
        this.block = block;
    }

    public void run(){
        if(block.pos.x < 0 || block.pos.x > 500){
            velX = -velX;
        }
        block.pos.x = block.pos.x + 1;
        repaint();
    }  
}
```

This is the code i have for the blocks and the movement, is there something i'm not considering for the movement?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the movement is a continuous action, then the `run` method needs to be a loop. The way you've written it, it will run once and only once. Add this to `MovementBlock`.

```
boolean running = true;
int frameDelay = 20; // ms

public void stop() { running = false; }

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            if (block.pos.x < 0 || block.pos.x > 500) {
                velX = -velX;
            }
            block.pos.x += velX;
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(frameDelay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```